# Ошибки валидации

Tags: валидация, html

Проверил на validator.w3, написал кучу ошибок почти все касаемые `/>` не пойму в чем проблема? ставлю / - ругается, убираю - опять ругается!? Может я чет с `DOCTYPE` напутал!? Я только учусь %)

[Ссылка на проверку](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxn--80aa8aajoeeg.xn--p1ai%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете HTML 4.01.
В нем НЕ НАДО закрывать одиночные тэги.
С каждым убранным лишним слэшем у меня уменьшалось число ошибок.
Кстати. Не всегда, когда он подсвечивает красным что-то, именно в этом месте ошибка.   Постарайтесь вникнуть в текст описания.

Comment: а какой HTML лучше всего использовать?))

Comment: 5-й, ес-но. У него и доктайп проще выглядит:

<!DOCTYPE html>

Вот у него придется закрывать одиночные тэги.
В любом случае, постарайтесь максимально избавиться от инлайновых скриптов

Comment: прошу прощения, а что такое инлайновые скрипты?)
и чет совсем жестко на 5, ошибок в 3 раза больше стало ((
в основном жалуется что мол элемент устарел %/

Comment: Инлайновые скрипты - это скрипты, тело которых описано прямо в html документе.
В норме, они все должны лежать в отдельных файлах, при необходимости сшиваемых в один перед выгрузкой.

и чет совсем жестко на 5, ошибок в 3 раза больше стало// Логично же. Он строже, поэтому я и предложил его использовать: 
меньше разночтений, 
больше разделение на стили, структуру и данные.

Чуть позже вы найдете много вкусных фишек.

Comment: хм, я для себя только открываю подобные вещи как стандарт и тд, раньше делал как захочется, теперь хочу подогнать все чтобы было чики-пики ) по поводу скриптов понял, по поводу увеличения ошибок тоже, а вот как их исправить, где подглядеть как правильно писать?

Comment: Как правильно писать  

 - скачать редактор с проверкой кода на лету. Самый быстрый вариант.  
 - проверять почаще, чтобы не оказываться перед роем ошибок. Самые интересные вещи записывать  
 - читать на чем-то типа [Школы Консорциума][1]
 - наконец, на сайте, где вы проходили валидацию есть ссылки на статьи на этом же сайте.  

  [1][http://w3schools.com]